# Can be any variable used in a schroot config?

Tags: schroot

I have more schroots but there are a base part which is the same in the all schroot configs (like users, type, etc.).

Can be this base file used/sourced in a schroot config file to avoid copying?

Comment: AFAICT, `schroot.conf` does not seem to support an `include` or similar directive.  You could fake it by concatenating schroot config fragments together to generate complete configs as you need them.  a Makefile would be useful to make sure that dependant configs are updated when one or more of their source fragment files is updated.